# What is the source of these verses from Adi Shankaracharya Sanskrit movie?

Tags: advaita, adi-shankaracharya, sanskrit, source

There is this beautiful couple of verses which are sung at the climax of [Adi Shankaracharya Sanskrit Movie](https://youtu.be/87wq0lSyebA?t=9256s).

This is a metaphorical depiction of dialogue between Shri Adi Shankaracharya and Personification of Jnana.

The verses are beautiful and sung melodically.

Shri Adi Shankara Says.

> संसार दुःखतप्तानां अज्ञान हतचेतसाम् । कामये सर्वलोकानां अद्वितीयात्म
> दर्शनम् ।।
>
> For the ones who are burned by the fire of Samsara, for the ones
> whose hopes are lost because of ignorance, for the entire world, I wish the
> vision and attainment of Atma(Brahman) who is without a second.

To which Personification of Jnana says
"Your logic is subtle and your philosophy is tough" and then sings

> ईश्वरानुग्रहादेव पुंसां अद्वैतवासना । ईश्वरानुग्रहो अद्य(?) का तत्र
> परिदेवना ।।
>
> It is only through the grace of the Lord, does one get the inclination
> of Advaita. If there is the grace of the lord (?), then what there is
> to lament over?

Now, second part of the second verse it's little unclear can any one clarify what exactly is the second verse and correct translation is?

From where are these beautiful verses taken from?

The first line of second verse seems to be present in Avadhoota Gita. Not sure about the first verse.

Are they composed only for this movie? Or are they found in any of our scriptures?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because is not a forum for movies. It is best to ask movie scriptwriters their sources - if any...

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda please be noted that your close vote will expire and this question won't be closed.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda Swamiji it is not that it is a movie question. It is more like that I heard this verse somewhere, is it found in scriptures? Only to give reference and context I linked the movie clip.